# RRC filter order

Tags: digital-communications

I have a question on rrc filter. Hope somebody can answer it.

**Tx path:**
My symbol rate is 1 mbps. I am using rrc 8x which becomes 8mpbs. For four symbols the order of the filter becomes 32. Next upsample by 10 becomes 80 mbps then followed by a low pass filter.

**Rx path:**
Easy thing is lowpass filter. Followed by downsample by 10. Then rrc filter with 8x at 8mbps. Then downsample to 1. Can I use downsample by 20 which will become 4 mbps. Then rrc filter with 4x at 4mbps? So order of the filter becomes 16?

Comment: Your symbol rate cannot be 1Mbps, it can be 1Msymbol/sec. If your over sampling factor is 8, your sampling rate is 8 Msample/sec, not *Msymbol/sec*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can likely downsample even to 2x per symbol which works well with timing recovery algorithms such as the Gardner. The trade space similar to any sampling rate decision is the increased filtering requirement prior to the downsample.

Evaluate the frequency response of your pulse shaping filter (for example with freqz in MATLAB/Octave or Python Scipy) for specific performance considerations, such as the stop band rejection based on the total span of the filter (number of taps) to ensure it is sufficient to not cause aliasing issues with too low of a downsampling rate.

Please see this post that further details the considerations for number of samples per symbol in the implementation of the RRC filter:

[Pulse shaping with RRC : Number of taps](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/51088/pulse-shaping-with-rrc-number-of-taps)

Another consideration will be how you are implementing timing recovery. You could certainly have an oversampled RRC filter such that you can select the best sample for your final downsample to 1 sample per symbol. However a more efficient approach would be to use 2 samples per symbol together with a 2 sample /symbol interpolator to position every other sample at the ideal location (all part of a timing recovery loop).

Comment: so u mean to say downsample to 2x per symbol and then use rrc filter later in the receiver chain. but filter taps will be different form transmit rrc. how to choose the filter taps? transmit i may be using upsample after RRC(filter length is more) and in the receiver i may use no downsample just plain rrc at 2x symbol??

Comment: I am not saying to change where in the receiver chain you use it but that wherever it is to be used, it can be done with a sample rate that low if the signal has been sufficiently filtered anywhere prior (even immediately) to the RRC. The length of the filter sets the attenuation you can achieve and the specific values are based on the roll-off factor of the RRC-- I will include some plots that show this.

Comment: You also see that the sampling rate you use in the receiver doesn't have anything to do with what you used in the transmitter since the signal in between is an analog signal the sampling rates are completely independent and not a consideration as to what you would do on the other side.

Comment: So not really critical that you use the same span in the receiver as you did in the transmitter. What is important is that you use the same roll-off factor.